# Reload UITableView on iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, apple-push-notifications

I have a system with Push Notification that needs to Update a `UITableView`. When a PN gets opened an method in the app delegate fires but obviously viewDidLoad runs before so the PN doesn't get added to the `UITableView`. How can I reload the `UITableView` when the PN comes in ? Also I don't want it to clear the `UITableView` when for example the 2nd PN comes in?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[tableView reloadData];` (`tableView` is the name of your `IBOutlet` or instance variable for the `UITableView`).